# how to access running container from the browser windows

Tags: docker

I want to access my running container from the browser docker in windows 10 pro
[image]

[image]

[image]

i can't access container IPs directly i try with http://localhost:8000 & http://172.17.0.3:8000

```
this is my Dockerfile

# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:16.15.1
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

i start my container from the interface docker

[image]

this the log
[image]

Comment: Can you also include your `Dockerfile` and the command you've used to start your container?

Comment: kingkupps i added Dockerfile and how i start the container

Comment: What's the actual `docker run` command you're running?  You in fact can't reach the Docker-internal IP addresses on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I forwarded the traffic from port 8080 to container port 3000 with this command it works now

```
docker run -d -p 8080:3000 expressdocker
```